# combo with search and button-reusable in extjs

Tags: extjs, datagrid, factory

i am using a factory function (which has  grids within windows called using button handler)within one form. 
so when i click the button and open a grid and than close it,it works correctly,
 but say for example in a situation:

if i open both grids and close , and than try to open other grid  the previous grids contents are loaded,but as i have set the store to load in button handler that particular store is loading correctly(i have checked with fire bug) but contents of grid are not changing

```
 win.hide();//use to hide the window after using it
closeAction: 'hide',//in window config
```

Comment: I agree, I really don't understand your question.

And do choose some answers among your previous questions - at least some of them are probably correct and helped you along the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using gridpanels for each of these grids.  You could force the stores to reload().  Or on the Window's close or hide event, you could try and clear the data on the store or reset the gridpanel.

You may want to read up on the closeAction property on the Window object.  That lets you define the behavior of the close button on the window.